# Turning navigation bar into a drop down navigation

Tags: html, navigation

I'm trying to edit my code so that when someone hovers over Products, it will drop down and show different sub categories, I want it to display 4 options, 450, 250, 2 strokes and Junior.

Here is my HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website.css">
<font face="Tahoma">
<font color="lightgray">
<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        font-family: Verdana,  Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;

      }
      .horizontal_menu {
        display: inline;
        text-align:center;
        border: 1px lightgray;
        background-color: white; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);

        margin: 2px;
        border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
        padding: 5px 20px;
        width: 800px;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
      .horizontal_menu li {
        text-align:center;
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 5px;
      }
      .horizontal_menu li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
      }
      .horizontal_menu li a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
    <ul class="horizontal_menu">
      <li>
        <a href="Homepage.php" title="Back to the home page">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="Products.php" title="Check out the products in stock">Products</a>
      </li>
        <li>
        <a href="aboutus.php" title="Check out the products in stock">About us</a>
      </li>
        <li>
        <a href="contact.php" title="Check out the products in stock">Contact</a>
      </li>
     </center> 

    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
<?php

?>
```

And my CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://p1.pichost.me/i/5/1282860.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}
h2 {
    color: lightgray;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
legend { 
    display: block;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    border: none;
}
div {

    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    background #dddddd;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

{
list-style:none;
list-style-type:none;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Nest your second list inside the first, below is an example of how this works. Here is a fiddle with a completed example:

http://jsfiddle.net/x5pmmcyq/

HTML:

```
  <ul class="horizontal_menu">
      <li>
        <a href="Homepage.php" title="Back to the home page">Home</a>
          <ul>
          <li>Nested Item</li>
          <li>Nested Item</li>
          <li>Nested Item</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
```

And then add in some CSS to get the hidden nested items to show on hover so this:

CSS:

```
.horizontal_menu li > ul {
        display: none       
}

.horizontal_menu li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }
```

The example used in the fiddle was taken from this site: 
http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Comment: Hi there, I put this into my code, however when I reload the homepage, the navigation bar now splits after products onto a new line and when I hover over it nothing appears!

Comment: Okay nevermind that was my fault, sorted it now, however, there is another problem, when I deleted "display: block;" from the CSS it started to work, however when the block is incorporated, the navigation bar goes crazy, splitting it up onto different lines

Comment: Can you copy your code into a fiddle like I have above so I can see the problem?